# Server Error, error serializing `getServerSideProps`

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

My console shows me that there is a problem with serving, which I can not solve:

```
Uncaught Error: Error serializing .title returned from getServerSideProps in "/property/[slug]".
Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use null or omit this value.
```

I am using sanity and next.js

This is my code from the slug component:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext) => {
  const pageSlug = pageContext.query.slug

  const query = `*[-type == "property" && slug.current == $pageSlug][0]{
    title,
    location,
    propertyType,
    mainImage,
    images,
    pricePerNight,
    beds,
    bedrooms,
    description,
    host->{
      _id,
      name,
      slug,
      image
    },
    reviews[]{
      ...,
      traveller->{
        _id,
        name,
        slug,
        image
      }
    }
  }`

  const property = await sanityClient.fetch(query, { pageSlug})

  if (!property) {
    return {
      props: null,
      notFound: true,
    }
  } else {
    return {
      props: {
        title: property.title,
        location: property.location,
        propertyType: property.propertyType,
        mainImage: property.mainImage,
        images: property.images,
        pricePerNight: property.pricePerNight,
        beds: property.beds,
        bedrooms: property.bedrooms,
        description: property.description,
        host: property.host,
        reviews: property.reviews
      }
    }
  }
}


export default Property
```

In my terminal, the client and server compiled successfully.

I tried to return `JSON.stringify` but still had no success.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#props), props object should be serializable to be fetched correctly by your rendered site. `undefined` values (just like functions) [are not serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description).

You can provide `null` fallback values for props which can be `undefined`:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  // some fetching logic
  return {
    props: {
      title: property.title || null
      // rest of props
    }
  }; 
}
```